# Failed to find the root WebApplicationContext. Or @ServerEndpoint @Autowired Variable is null

Tags: java, spring, autowired, java-websocket

First of all:
I created a WebSocket with this Tutorial [Java EE WebSocket](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html) because I cannot use the SockJS or Stompway. I have to use Plain Websocket.

Now after sometime this is my Main Controller. 
WSServerEndpint.java

```
package com.doka.websocket;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.SpringConfigurator;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;*

@Controller
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/var", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class, encoders={MessageEncoder.class, MessageEncoderBinary.class},
        decoders={MessageDecoder.class, MessageDecoderBinary.class})
public class WSServerEndpoint {

@Autowired
ServerEndpointDelegateImpl delegate;


@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
}
@OnOpen
public void open(Session session) {
    delegate.onConnect(session);
    System.out.println("Session created with id :" + session.getId());
}

@OnClose
public void close(Session session) {
    delegate.onDisconnect(session);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, MessageText message) {
    delegate.onMessage(session, message);
    System.out.println(message);
}
@OnMessage
public void onMessageBinary(Session session, MessageBinary message)
{
    delegate.onMessage(session, message);
    System.out.println(message);
}


public WSServerEndpoint(){
}
```

This Will run if i simply remove the `configurator = SpringConfigurator.class` but then the `@Autowired ServerEndpointDelegateImpl delegate` will always be null.

I also tried to create the object in the Constructor like this:

```
public WSServerEndpoint(){
    delegate = new ServerEndpointDelegateImpl();
}
```

Then the Application launches and also the OnOpen will run correctly but later in the Code I am using follwing function:

```
public class AuthenticationChannelImpl extends DefaultAuthentication     implements AuthenticationChannel
{

@Autowired
private MongoDBApp mongoDBApp;
[...]
for(ConnectionProfile connectionProfile : mongoDBApp.getConnectionRepository().findAll()){
[...]
}
```

And then i have the same problem like before. mongoDBApp will be null.

So my guess is that I'm doing something wrong in WSServerEndpoint.java or I'm using the @Autowired wrong.

Here is my Endpointconfig.java:

```
package com.doka.websocket;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter;

@Configuration
public class EndpointConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter = new ServerEndpointExporter();
        serverEndpointExporter.setAnnotatedEndpointClasses(WSServerEndpoint.class);
        return serverEndpointExporter;
}
```

Things I also found and tried:
(Sorry for misformatting but I"m not allwoed to post more then 2 links but i thought this would be relevant.)

- github .com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/321 (maybe relevant because I'm using a embedded Tomcat)
- stackoverflow .com/questions/30483094/springboot-serverendpoint-failed-to-find-the-root-webapplicationcontext/31183517#31183517 (Seems to use Not the Standard Websocket)
- spring .io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support (adds the SpringConfigurator.class which leads to the described problem if removed all my Autowired Variables are zero)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to autowire Spring bean to EE bean. I am afraid this won't work

Comment: What exception do you get when the `configurator = SpringConfigurator.class` is present?

Comment: @itachi `Failed to find the root WebApplicationContext. Was ContextLoaderListener not used?` this one do I get

Comment: @stanislavl He was right. After migrating it to Spring the Autowired fields are working. 

So i cannot mix Java EE and Spring.

Comment: Actually there is a way. Introduce a bridge between EE and Spring but I guess it's not simple thing and really buggy/time consuming.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply time. But I took the "easy way" and changed my code from Java EE to Spring and now everything works as supposed to.